# Disable Client Isolation when using hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, 9.0-pie

I just moved to a new place and internet is not setup yet so I'm using my phone's hotspot to get online. While developing a Python client-server program I found out that devices connected to Android hotspot cannot communicate with each other. When I ping one computer from another I get a "Destination host unreachable" message. This must be some sort of client isolation. Does anybody know how to turn it off? Using latest crDroid on Android 9.

[UPDATE]
I run a few more ping tests and they seem pretty inconclusive. I got some hits but the results vary between 'Host unreachable', 'Request timed out' and various TTL times (6ms to 4000ms).

Comment: Android uses `hostapd` as its AP daemon. [hostapd.conf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/hostapd/hidl/1.0/hostapd.cpp) file which AOSP creates doesn't contain [ap_isolate=1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/hostapd/hostapd.conf#505). But may be your OEM has added that to configuration file. You can check that with root: `cat /data/vendor/wifi/hostapd/hostapd_*.conf`. Do you ping the hosts by IP or hostname?

Comment: @IrfanLatif I pinged the hosts by IP that I found from executing ipconfig on cmd. I found the `hostpad_wlan1.conf` file using a root browser and I can confirm that there is no ap_isolate=1 line in there. Maybe it's 1 by default and I should write ap_isolate=0? As I said I'm using a custom ROM so not sure what you mean by my OEM (wouldn't that be Xiaomi for example?).

Comment: Sorry I missed the custom ROM point. `ap_isolate` is not set by default. There must be some issues with your networking. Use `tcpdump` or `iptables -j LOG` for troubleshooting.

Comment: Updated the post with new data.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier watch traffic on both sides using `tcpdump` when pinging. Even better do `ip n flush all` and then use `arping` and watch. See the [state](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html#ex-ether-arp-cache) of arp requests on both sides. That would give some clue where the problem is.

Comment: I have tried with Android 9 by HTC and the connection between clients works. Although I had to wait for it for about 2 minutes (been waiting on a ping loop).

Comment: I can confirm that with enough patience, it starts to work (HTC U11), which is quite confusing. I always assumed AP isolation is enabled until reading @OndraŽižka's comment.